# DOMException error when I change the variable name (type) I pass to the blob option object

Tags: javascript

this js code works fine:

```
var text="copy me"
var type = 'text/plain';
var blob = new Blob([text], { type });
var data = [new ClipboardItem({ [type]: blob })];
navigator.clipboard.write(data)
```

But if I change the `type` variable name to something else, the code throws an error even though no changes to the code logic or syntax has been made, example:

```
var text="copy me"
var anotherName= 'text/plain';
var blob = new Blob([text], { anotherName});
var data = [new ClipboardItem({ [anotherName]: blob })];
navigator.clipboard.write(data)
```

The error I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Type text/plain does not match the blob's type
```

why would using a different name than `type` triggers an error ?

Comment: The option that Blob is expecting in named `type` so you can use any name you like for the variable but you need to refer to it by the key type in the options object. `{type: anotherName}`. Passing a single variable name in an object is shorthand: `{type}` is equivalent to `{type: type}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) accepts an option object as its second argument which can specify two properties `type` and `endings`.

```
var newBlob = new Blob(array, {type: '', endings: 'transparent'});
```

In your first, working, example you are defining this object using the [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) which works since your variable is named `type` and `Blob()` expects a `type` property.

```
var type = 'text/plain';
var blob = new Blob([text], { type });
// equivalent to: var blob = new Blob([text], { type: type });
```

But in your second example you are creating an options object with a property name that `Blob()` does not recognize, and you aren't specifying `type` at all.

```
var anotherName= 'text/plain';
var blob = new Blob([text], { anotherName});
// equivalent to: var blob = new Blob([text], { anotherName: anotherName });
```

You can solve this by explicitly declaring the key in the options object.

```
var anotherName= 'text/plain';
var blob = new Blob([text], { type: anotherName});
```

Note: your use of the variable name in declaring the key in the `new ClipboardItem()` call is same regardless of the name of the variable.